# Kibana JSON files are not loading

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using Kibana 3.0.1 and elastsearch 1.1.1

Everything was working fine and then suddenly the JSON files stopped loading.

There are no panels showing at all and it's just a completely blank Kibana page.

Comment: Is there any javascript error in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this happen after moving the elasticsearch index location? I had the same issue after I moved the index files for elasticsearch to a new partition.  After loading Kibana I only had a blank dashboard and I noticed 404 errors in the developer tools of Chrome (press F12).  The 404 errors were pointing to 
`http://localhost:9200/kibana-int/dashboard/dashboardname`.  I tried to hit that URL in a browser and received this

> {"error":"IndexMissingException[[kibana-int] missing]","status":404}

After checking the indexes on my elasticsearch instance, I found that kibana-int was missing

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
```

I found that my data was moved to an incorrect data location.  I found my old kibana-int index and moved it to path where current indexes are stored, restarted elasticsearch and my data appeared